# Qiskit QFT matrix does not match with DFT matrix

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-fourier-transform

The unitary matrix associated with the `QFT` circuit in Qiskit does not match the actual DFT matrix. In fact, all the imaginary components have their sign flipped (QFT and DFT matrices seems to be each other's complex conjugate). Is that the correct behavior?

Note that the `QFT` circuit already includes the swap gates at the end of the circuit.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import dft
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import QFT

n = 2
dft_matrix = (1/np.sqrt(2**n)) * dft(2**n)
qft_matrix = execute(QFT(n), Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')).result().get_unitary()

# remove components almost zero for enhanced visualization
eps = 0.00001
dft_matrix.real[np.abs(dft_matrix.real) < eps] = 0
dft_matrix.imag[np.abs(dft_matrix.imag) < eps] = 0
qft_matrix.real[np.abs(qft_matrix.real) < eps] = 0
qft_matrix.imag[np.abs(qft_matrix.imag) < eps] = 0

dft_matrix, qft_matrix
```

The matrices have values:

```
dft_matrix=
array([[  0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j ],
        [ 0.5+0.j ,  0. -0.5j, -0.5+0.j ,  0. +0.5j],
        [ 0.5+0.j , -0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j , -0.5+0.j ],
        [ 0.5+0.j ,  0. +0.5j, -0.5+0.j ,  0. -0.5j]]),
qft_matrix=
array([[  0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j ],
        [ 0.5+0.j ,  0. +0.5j, -0.5+0.j ,  0. -0.5j],
        [ 0.5+0.j , -0.5+0.j ,  0.5+0.j , -0.5+0.j ],
        [ 0.5+0.j ,  0. -0.5j, -0.5+0.j ,  0. +0.5j]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs of [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.dft.html) and [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-fourier-transform.html), the first uses primitive root $\omega = e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ and the second uses $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$.

This implies that one matrix is complex conjugate of the other (which is the same as inverse).