# Different QFT and classical FFT result

Tags: qiskit, quantum-fourier-transform

I tried to create a PoC that QFT and classical (np.fft) are the same; however, the result confuses me. I use the same input for both QFT and np.fft. I used simulator circuit and directly measured the vector so there shouldn't be any noise.
Here is my code.

```
import qiskit
from qiskit.providers.aer.extensions.snapshot_statevector import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

sample_norm = [0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0]
n = len(sample_norm)
q = int(math.log(n,2))

# Start the QFT circuit
circuit = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(q)
circuit.initialize(sample_norm, range(q))
circuit.snapshot_statevector('init') # This vector is correct
circuit += qiskit.circuit.library.QFT(num_qubits=q, do_swaps=False, approximation_degree=0)
circuit.snapshot_statevector('qft')
circuit.measure_all()

aer_sim = qiskit.Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
qobj = qiskit.assemble(circuit)
result = aer_sim.run(qobj, shots=1).result()
init_vec = result.data()["snapshots"]["statevector"]["init"][0]
qft_vec = result.data()["snapshots"]["statevector"]["qft"][0]

PSD_q = np.real(qft_vec * np.conj(qft_vec))

# Classical np.fft
f = sample_norm
fhat = np.fft.fft(f,n)
PSD = np.real(fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n)

plt.plot(PSD_q, color='r', linewidth=2, label='QTF')
plt.plot(PSD, color='c', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, label='npFFT')
plt.xlim(0, n)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image: Text]

I understand that there may be different in scaling but the result doesn't look like an effect from scaling. I have also tried with do_swaps=True/False but it doesn't help either. The vectors I got from the snapshot also don't look similar. (And not just the conjugate part)

```
eps = 0.000000001
qft_vec.real[np.abs(qft_vec.real) < eps] = 0
qft_vec.imag[np.abs(qft_vec.imag) < eps] = 0
fhat.real[np.abs(fhat.real) < eps] = 0
fhat.imag[np.abs(fhat.imag) < eps] = 0

qft_vec
array([0.70710678+0.j       , 0.1767767 +0.4267767j,
       0.        +0.j       , 0.1767767 +0.0732233j,
       0.        +0.j       , 0.1767767 -0.0732233j,
       0.        +0.j       , 0.1767767 -0.4267767j])

fhat
array([2.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 2.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j])
```

I'm actually a beginner in both QFT and FFT but I have read many sources, the result from both QFT and FFT should be similar? Even the matrix is only different in the complex conjugate part. [Qiskit QFT matrix does not match with DFT matrix](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17259/qiskit-qft-matrix-does-not-match-with-dft-matrix)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code with different vectors like $[0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4]$ and $[0.4, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0.5, 0.3]$ and it worked without any issue. Upgrading Qiskit to the latest version fixes this issue.

> I have also tried with do_swaps=True/False but it doesn't help either.

You need to set `do_swaps` to `True`.

Comment: I have already tried that. It looks bit better for some init_vector and worse for the others so I don't think this is the cause? Here is the result from vector [0.5,0.5,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0] when do_swaps=True: https://imgur.com/1rORMU5

Comment: I tested your code with this vector also and it worked perfectly fine! 
Then I tried other vectors like [0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4] and [0.4, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0.5, 0.3]. Again, it worked without any issue. What's your Qiskit version?

Comment: It's qiskit 0.24.0 Wow, I didn't think this would be the case so I have forgotten about the qiskit version; it's very old already. Just updated to 0.34.2. I'm now getting error on statevector API, let me fix that and I will check the result again.

Comment: After upgrade you need to replace `qobj = qiskit.assemble(circuit)` with `qobj = qiskit.transpile(circuit, aer_sim)`. The remaining are warnings not errors.

Comment: You're right about the qiskit version. I am now getting the correct result on every vector. Could you please add this to the original answer? I will mark yours as correct answer. Thank you so much.